# Visual Studio Test Project

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I've created a new MVC2 project as well as a Tests project within my solution. I have not yet done anything to the default tests nor am I experienced with them. I've seen a webinar on web tests and measuring performance using Test Professional. Are these completely different?

Can the Tests project inside my solution be used by Test Professional, or are these tests only good for Visual Studio/a developer?

I briefly read that you can use Team Foundation Server to collaborate on tests but that is not currently an option for me. And again, I'm not sure if that would help as I don't know if tests created in VS can be used in Test Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question in part:

From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional):

> Using Visual Studio Test Professional
>   2010 requires an active Visual Studio
>   Team Foundation Server 2010 (TFS)
>   instance to link to in order to run.
>   If your group does not already have a
>   TFS 2010 server available, then for
>   the purposes of evaluating the Test
>   Professional Trial we recommend you
>   download and install TFS 2010 using
>   the Basic install option.

Comment: Ah, well I obviously missed that. Thanks

Comment: That part about it being able to open standard Visual Studio Test Projects is difficult to find.